# DRF: how to call post method once the put method has been successfully implemented

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two separate methods:

1. to load and validate a csv file FileUploadView(APIView) [PUT]
2. to add new objects to the database based on their uploaded file data
   CsvToDatabase [POST]

For this purpose, 2 different url addresses are used

Now I want to combine this functionality into one, so that the file is loaded with processing and creation of instances in the database is done on a single request. That is, the final goal - the application user sends the file to the server and then everything happens automatically.

**file upload**

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        if 'file' not in request.data:
            raise ParseError("Empty content")
        f = request.data['file']
        filename = f.name
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            file = default_storage.save(filename, f)
            r = csv_file_parser(file)
            status = 204
            print(json.dumps(r))
        else:
            status = 406
            r = "File format error"
        return Response(r, status=status)
```

**create instances**

```
class CsvToDatabase(APIView):


    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = VendorsCsvSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        r_data = request.data
        ...
        #some logic
        ...
            serializer = VendorsCsvSerializer(data=data)
            try:
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                serializer.save()
            except ValidationError:
                return Response({"errors": (serializer.errors,)},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

how can I correctly combine two methods in one endpoint so that if csv file validation is successful, the POST method will be called? Or maybe it's better to leave two different urls and send the json received after parsing the .csv file to the url with the POST method? This option seems to me easier to test.  but how do I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    # renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = VendorsCsvSerializer

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        if 'file' not in request.data:
            raise ParseError("Empty content")
        f = request.data['file']
        filename = f.name
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            file = default_storage.save(filename, f)
            r = csv_file_parser(file)
            status = 204
            response = Response(r)
            self.post(request=response)
        else:
            status = 406
            r = "File format error"
        return Response(r, status=status)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        r_data = request.data
        ....
            serializer = VendorsCsvSerializer(data=data)
            try:
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                serializer.save()
            except ValidationError:
                return Response({"errors": (serializer.errors,)},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I hope this is the right way